# Paypal not returning custom variable

Tags: node.js, express, paypal, graphql, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to complete a paypal transaction using paypal-rest-sdk, everything is set up and working, however, I need to get the clientId back from paypal in the success route in order to save it in my client_feature_payment model. I found that we can set a "custom" field where we can set anything and that'll be sent back by paypal but this feautre is available in classic paypal sdk only and not available in rest-sdk one.
Is there any workaround for this?

/**/Paypal objects and methods from rest-sdk:**

```
client_page: {
      args: {
        clientId: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      type: ClientType,
      resolve: async (_, args) => {
        if (args.clientId) {
          let clientMongoId = fromGlobalId(args.clientId).id;
          let client = await Client.queryOne("id")
            .eq(clientMongoId)
            .exec();
          let clientName = client.name;
          let clientSecret = client.secret;
      let company = await Company.queryOne("id")
        .eq(client.companyId)
        .exec();
      let companyName = company.name;

      let service = await Service.queryOne("id")
        .eq(client.serviceId)
        .exec();
      let serviceName = service.name;

      let clientFeature = await ClientFeature.query("clientId")
        .eq(clientMongoId)
        .exec();

      let totalFeatures = [];
      let clientFeatureId = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < clientFeature.length; i++) {
        clientFeatureId.unshift(clientFeature[i].id);

        let feature = await Feature.query("id")
          .eq(clientFeature[i].featureId)
          .exec();
        let newFeature;
        feature.map(
          feature =>
            (newFeature = [
              feature.name,
              feature.cost,
              feature.trial,
              feature.frequency
            ])
        );
        totalFeatures.unshift(newFeature);
      }

      let trial, freq;
      let cost = [];
      totalFeatures.map(item => {
        if (item[2] && item[3]) {
          trial = item[2];
          freq = item[3];
        }
        cost.unshift(item[1]);
      });

      const finalCost = cost.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        return accumulator + currentValue;
      }, 0);
      let paypalFreq;
      let frequencyInterval;
      var isoDate = new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 60 * 1000);

      switch (freq) {
        case "bi-weekly":
          paypalFreq = "DAY";
          frequencyInterval = "7";
          break;
        case "monthly":
          paypalFreq = "MONTH";
          frequencyInterval = "1";
          break;
        case "3 months":
          paypalFreq = "MONTH";
          frequencyInterval = "3";
          break;
        case "6 months":
          paypalFreq = "MONTH";
          frequencyInterval = "6";
          break;
        case "1 year":
          paypalFreq = "YEAR";
          frequencyInterval = "1";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      var billingPlanAttributes = {
        description:
          "Create Plan for Trial & Frequency based payment for features and services used by customer",
        merchant_preferences: {
          auto_bill_amount: "yes",
          cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
          initial_fail_amount_action: "continue",
          max_fail_attempts: "1",
          return_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
          setup_fee: {
            currency: "USD",
            value: "0"
          }
        },
        name: "Client Services & Features Charge",
        payment_definitions: [
          {
            amount: {
              currency: "USD",
              value: finalCost
            },
            cycles: "0",
            frequency: paypalFreq,
            frequency_interval: frequencyInterval,
            name: "Regular 1",
            type: "REGULAR"
          },
          {
            amount: {
              currency: "USD",
              value: "0"
            },
            cycles: "1",
            frequency: "DAY",
            frequency_interval: trial,
            name: "Trial 1",
            type: "TRIAL"
          }
        ],
        type: "INFINITE"
      };

      var billingPlanUpdateAttributes = [
        {
          op: "replace",
          path: "/",
          value: {
            state: "ACTIVE"
          }
        }
      ];

      var billingAgreementAttr = {
        name: "Fast Speed Agreement",
        description: "Agreement for Fast Speed Plan",
        start_date: isoDate,
        plan: {
          id: "P-0NJ10521L3680291SOAQIVTQ"
        },
        payer: {
          payment_method: "paypal",
          payer_info: {
            payer_id: clientMongoId
          }
        },
        shipping_address: {
          line1: "StayBr111idge Suites",
          line2: "Cro12ok Street",
          city: "San Jose",
          state: "CA",
          postal_code: "95112",
          country_code: "US"
        }
      };

      // Create the billing plan
      let billingPlan = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        paypal.billingPlan.create(
          billingPlanAttributes,
          (error, billingPlan) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            } else {
              resolve(billingPlan);
            }
          }
        );
      });

      // let billingPlan = await billingPlanPromise;

      // Activate the plan by changing status to Active
      let billingAgreementAttributes = await new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
          paypal.billingPlan.update(
            billingPlan.id,
            billingPlanUpdateAttributes,
            (error, response) => {
              if (error) {
                throw error;
              } else {
                billingAgreementAttr.plan.id = billingPlan.id;
                resolve(billingAgreementAttr);
              }
            }
          );
        }
      );

      // Use activated billing plan to create agreement
      let approval_url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        paypal.billingAgreement.create(
          billingAgreementAttributes,
          (error, billingAgreement) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            } else {
              for (
                var index = 0;
                index < billingAgreement.links.length;
                index++
              ) {
                if (billingAgreement.links[index].rel === "approval_url") {
                  var approval_url = billingAgreement.links[index].href;
                  let newApprovalUrl =
                    approval_url + `&custom=${clientFeatureId}`;
                  resolve(newApprovalUrl);

                  // See billing_agreements/execute.js to see example for executing agreement
                  // after you have payment token
                }
              }
            }
          }
        );
      });

      let data = {
        companyId: companyName,
        serviceId: serviceName,
        name: clientName,
        secret: clientSecret,
        features: totalFeatures,
        endpoint: approval_url
      };

      return Object.assign(data);
    }
  }
},
```

**The success route:**

```
app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
    console.log("This is response", res);
    let paymentToken = req.query.token;
    paypal.billingAgreement.execute(paymentToken, {}, function(
      error,
      billingAgreement
    ) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log("Billing agreement", billingAgreement);
        let date = billingAgreement.start_date;
        let amountString =
          billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[1].amount.value;
        let trial =
          billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[0].frequency_interval;
        let frequencyInterval =
          billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[1].frequency_interval;
        let frequency = billingAgreement.plan.payment_definitions[1].frequency;
        let totalFrequency = frequencyInterval + " " + frequency;
        let period = [trial, totalFrequency];
        let amount = parseInt(amountString);
        try {
          Payment.create({
            id: uuidv1(),
            date: date,
            amount: amount,
            period: period
          });
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
        res.render("index");
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation looks very different, but I can output any payment details. My payment.execute() looks like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk");
const app = express;

paypal.configure({
  mode: "sandbox", //sandbox or live
  client_id:
    "...",
  client_secret:
    "..."
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("index"));

app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
  const create_payment_json = {
    intent: "sale",
    payer: {
      payment_method: "paypal"
    },
    redirect_urls: {
      return_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    transactions: [
      {
        item_list: {
          items: [
            {
              name: "Item",
              sku: "001",
              price: "3.33",
              currency: "USD",
              quantity: 1
            }
          ]
        },
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: "3.33"
        },
        description:
          "Hope this helps."
      }
    ]
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      // console.log("Create Payment Response");
      // console.log(payment.id);
      // res.send('test')
      for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
  const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  const execute_payment_json = {
    payer_id: payerId,
    transactions: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: "3.33"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function(
    error,
    payment
  ) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      throw error;
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));   
    }
  });
});

app.get("/cancel", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Cancelled");
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Started"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you tell me what are you passing in paymentId and execute_payment_json??

Comment: Actually, the code you provided seems like to be of transaction based, I'm looking for subscription based instead, as you can see from the code I've  posted above. So, if you have any insights on subscription based payment, please provide those.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, too newb to understand that. Don't know anything about it. Good luck!!!